# Как ограничить область рисования?

Tags: winapi, windows, c++

Имеется программа на WinAPI (C++), в которой рисуется на области фигуры. Что нужно сделать, чтобы рисование не происходило и по панели инструментов, где расположены инструменты для рисования?

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. располагать панель инструментов в другом окне (было бы логично)
2. рисовать с учетом границ, в которые необходимо уместиться, это так же скажется на производительности ПО, особенно, если велика область за пределами границ
3. использовать API: **IntersectClipRect** или **SelectClipRgn**, этого обычно хватает